# College Student need helps on homework in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, collections

Hi so im trying to complete this homework for a class and it involves reading a file and pulling out the duplicates into an array list. What I am getting stuck on is comparing my elements in my array list. I keep getting an IndexOutOfBounds error when trying to compare my elements

```
for(int i=0;i<=counter;i++) {
            for(int j=i+1;j<=counter;j++) {
                if(uniqueWords.get(i) == uniqueWords.get(j)) {
                    dup.add(uniqueWords.get(i));
                }
            }
```

both my counter and uniqueWords list are size of 4 however I still get an IndexOutOfBounds error.I tested this code in a test project but ran the code with just the number '4' in the boolean expression for the length and it ran fine but when I use my counter variable it doesn't seem to work. Any feedback would be greatly appreacited.

Comment: What is the size of `uniqueWords`?

Comment: What is the value of `uniqueWords.size()` and `counter`?

Comment: If they are both are 4, you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException with `uniqueWords.get(4)`. Indices are zero-based.

Comment: they are both size of 4

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I see what you mean thank you

Comment: You "could" use a `Set`, but probably aren't allowed to.  You could use a `Map` of some kind and find the number of times a word repeats, but you're probably not allowed to.  You could use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` and test to see if they are the same 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`counter` is the size of the list, hence the maximum index is `counter + 1`. In your loop you're not only iterating from 0 to `counter` inclusively, but also assign `j=i+1`. It should be like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < counter; j++) {
        if(uniqueWords.get(i) == uniqueWords.get(j)) {
            dup.add(uniqueWords.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm dumb. Thank you!